# jQuery: remove certain elements from HTML document

Tags: jquery, tags

I'd like to strip certain elements from my HTML document.
It seems that removing some tags simply doesn't work.

For example - strip all stylesheets:

```
$("style",this._doc.body).remove();
```

I'd also like to remove comments or something like weird winword tags like: 
`<!--[if gte mso 9]>`

How to do it?

Comment: Can you post the total HTML and what you want to remove?

Comment: i've updated my text - i want to strip all stylesheet files.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all stylesheets, try this:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
```

Comment: would it be possible also stripping all style definitions? like <style>...</style>

Comment: yes, iirc try
  $('style').remove();
if that doesn't work, try
  $('style').each(function() { $(this).remove(); });